# ".." won't be accepted in Alloy?

Tags: alloy

I have found an example of an Alloy code in an article I've been reading, this is a snippet of it :

```
fun Object::equals(obj: Object) { this.class = Object_Class => this..Object_equals(obj) this.class = Dimension_Class => this..Dimension_equals(obj) this.class = Dimension3D_Class
=>this..Dimension3D_equals(obj) }
```

But the ".." is not recognized in the Alloy analyzer. Does any one know if it could be replaced by another operator?

Comment: can you link the article? Maybe with the date we can find out what the author meant to do with the sentence or find by the date if the syntax was different then

Comment: Yes ofcurse, @BernardoFerreiraBastosBraga the article is : http://users.ece.utexas.edu/~khurshid/testera/valloy.pdf